# Solving $Ae^{Bx}+Cx+D=0$

Tags: problem-solving, exponential-function

Is it possible in general to solve equations of the form $Ae^{Bx}+Cx+D=0$? The most I have been able to do is rearrange the equation as $(Bx+\frac{BD}{C})=-\frac{AB}{C}e^{-\frac{BD}{C}}e^{(Bx+\frac{BD}{C})}$, which is in the form of $x=Ae^x$ for $(Bx+\frac{BD}{C})$ which looks solvable. However I don't know how. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You'll need the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to express the solution.

Comment: Solution in terms of Lambert W function (for approximate solutions use a Taylor expansion of the exponential), see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3658405/532409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), $x=a\mathrm e^x$ can be rewritten as $(-x)\mathrm e^{-x}=-a$, hence $x=-W(-a)$.

Note that this is not much more than a rewriting of the equation, hence the fact that Lambert W function was given a definition and that $x$ can be expressed through it does not lead us closer to a "solution", if you ask me.

Comment: @Did Well, at least I have a Taylor series to play with (therefore approximate solutions).

Comment: Right. If you happy, me happy. :-)