# Solving equations of the form $ae^x + bx +c =0$

Tags: exponential-function

In a recent piece of homework I needed to solve an equation of the form $ae^x + bx +c = 0$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are constants. I could not do it; no matter how I tried I either went in circles or hit a brick wall. Can someone demonstrate a general method for solving equations of this form? Please show every step in your answers.

Comment: This [article on exponential-linear equations](http://www1.american.edu/cas/mathstat/People/kalman/pdffiles/glog.pdf) focuses on these type of equations.

Comment: See there : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479776/solving-aebxcxd-0?rq=1
Short answer, there are no easy solution.

Comment: @PaulPicard Hmm. Well the solution can't be a complex number (since that wouldn't make sense in the context of the question), so I guess I've done something wrong. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: See [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @Lucian Like I say the solution can't be a complex number. I've done something wrong

Comment: @imulsion: Who said that there's only one solution ? And why, pray tell, can't at least some of them be complex ? And how on earth would you even know their nature, since the values of the three parameters are not even given ?

Comment: @Lucian See my previous comment. Complex numbers do not make sense in the context of my homework question.

Comment: @imulsion: The function has more than just one branch. The complex numbers in question may not be the only solutions. What are the values of *a*, *b*, and *c* ?

Comment: Known a,b and c, can't we just easily plot and solve?

Comment: @Lucian I have $5-12x = 88e^x$. I can solve it easily using the equations function on my calculator (the answer is about $0.303$), but I know that I need to use an algebraic method. As I've said, I've done something wrong. I'm only at A Level and that function is beyond my level of study.

Comment: Solution in terms of Lambert W function (for approximate solutions use a Taylor expansion of the exponential), see: math.stackexchange.com/a/3658405/532409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
a e^{x}+b x+c&=0
\end{align}
Substitute $bx+c=y$:
\begin{align}
a e^{((-c+y)/b)}+y &= 0
\\
-y &= ae^{-c/b}e^{y/b}  
\\
\frac{-y}{b}e^{-y/b} &= \frac ab e^{-c/b} 
\end{align}
The last equation is in the form $u\exp(u)=w$,
which has a solution in terms of Lambert $W$ function:
\begin{align}
u&=W(w).
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\frac{-y}{b}&=W(\frac ab e^{(-c/b)})
\\
y&=-b W(a/b e^{\frac{-c}{b})}
\\
x&=-W(\frac ab e^{-c/b})- \frac cb.
\end{align}
In particular, equation $88\exp(x)+12x-5=0$
with $a=88,b=12,c=-5$ has one real root,
since the argument of $W$ is positive:
\begin{align}
x&=-W_0(\frac{22}{3} e^\frac{5}{12}))+\frac{5}{12}
\approx-1.3970513.
\end{align}

**Edit:**

Lambert's W function is included in the Gnu Scientific Library (GSL)
and is freely available by means of many computer systems and packages
(wolframalpha, R, Asymptote, python scipy.special to name a few).

Answer (score 2):

As said, there is an analytical solution in terms of Lambert function $$x=-W(d)-\frac{c}{b}$$ where $$d=\frac{a }{b}e^{-\frac{c}{b}}$$ If you do not want to (or cannot)  use Lambert function, then numerical methods are the way to go.

Probably the simplest should be Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For the example you give in comments $$f(x)=5-12x - 88e^x$$ $$f'(x)=-12-88e^x$$ A look at the graph of the function shows that the solution is close to $-1.5$. So, let start iterating at $x_0=-1.5$; the method will generates the following iterates : $-1.393646353$, $-1.397047564$, $-1.397051301$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Comment: I've definitely done it wrong then - my solution has to be positive to make sense in the context of the question. thanks anyway though :)

Comment: May be, there was a typo in the equation. In any manner, you are very welcome !