# Solving equations of the form $axe^x+bx+c=0$

Tags: exponential-function

Recently, I am trying to derive an algorithm where one step requires me to solve the equation of the form $axe^x+bx+c=0$ where $a, b, c$ are all constant and $x$ is a scalar variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend adding your attempt or thought process for the questions.

Comment: Thanks @zaira. I tried to solve this question using https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238668 as a hint. But I cannot write the equation into the form of $u e^u = w$ as suggested by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238745. And now I have no idea how to solve this question.

Comment: I shall  continue tomorrow morning (dinner time here)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: enjoy your meal.

Comment: Rather than leaving such context in the comments and being vague in the question, you should [edit] the question to include these details. Others may be interested, or such context may help drive answers. This also includes other information, such as the possible values of $a,b,c$ for example. Your tags include [tag:matrix-exponential], which suggests these may be matrices. If so, what are their dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most general case, there is no explicit solution to this equation except the [generalized Lambert equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) since you can write
$$e^{-x}=-\frac{a x}{b x+c}$$ (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper.

This being said, it is nice but not very useful from a practical point of view; so, numerical methods are required and, as a consequence, reasonable starting points.

Without any loss of generality, assuming $a \neq 0$ we can divide all coefficient by $a$ or , simpler, let $a=1$. Now, consider that we look for the zero('s) of function
$$f(x)=xe^x+bx+c$$ for which
$$f'(x)=e^x (x+1)+b \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=e^x (x+2)$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$x_1=W(-eb)-1$$ where appears Lambert function. In the real domain, this point exists if $b \leq \frac 1{e^2}$.

At this point, we have
$$f(x_1)=b W(-e b)+\frac{b}{W(-eb)}-2 b+c $$ $$f''(x_1)= - b \left(1+\frac{1}{W(-eb)}\right)$$
We must notice that
$$f(x_1)-c=b W(-e b)+\frac{b}{W(-eb)}-2 b$$ is always negative.

So, if $c <0$, no root. If $c=0$, two possible roots located at $x=0$ and $x=-\log(-b)$ (if the last does exist). If $c<0$, two roots.

There is also an inflection point at
$$x_2=-2 \implies f(x_2)=-2 b+c-\frac{2}{e^2}$$ So, if $c<2b+\frac{2}{e^2}$, another possible root.

There two roots that we can locate more or less since the will be on each side of $x_1$. Building a Taylor series around $x_1$, we have as estimates
$$x_\pm=x_1 \pm \sqrt{-2 \frac {f(x_1)}{f''(x_1)}}$$

For example, let us try for $b=-0.1$ and $c=-1$. This will give $x_+=1.36$  and $x_-=-2.92$. So, using Newton method, the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -2.92363 \\
 1 & -7.17566 \\
 2 & -9.92501 \\
 3 & -10.0045 
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.36058 \\
 1 & 0.90268 \\
 2 & 0.65533 \\
 3 & 0.59170 \\
 4 & 0.58807 \\
 5 & 0.58806
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a hint.

The equation can be written in the form

$$xe^x=mx+p,$$ which represents the intersection between a transcendental curve and an arbitrary straight line. The curve has an inflection point and there can be up to three solutions.

[image]

To discuss the number of roots, you can rely on the tangents that have the slope $m$. Unfortunately, this leads to a nasty equation,

$$(x+1)e^x=m$$ that requires the Lambert function, with

$$x=W(em)-1.$$ There can be two solutions. The intercept of the tangent is then

$$xe^x-mx$$ which you compare to your $p$ to determine the number of solutions and to isolate them between the contact points.

Comment: It seems that I missed one. Cheers